# How can I apply a script to only one specific sheet within a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets called `Robin` and `Lucy`. I've made/found/mangled a script to sort the data on the sheet each time I add some data to column A:

```
function onEdit(event){

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "a2:I30";
    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
   var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
   range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

This script works well but I only want it it be applied on the first sheet, `Robin`. The data in the second sheet, `Lucy`, isn't the same so I'm going to create another script for a different range for that one, once I get my head around this problem.

I think I need to use the `getSheetByName("Robin")` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 17):

There are a couple of ways to do that. First, you need to declare the spreadsheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Secondly, declare the first sheet like this:

```
var sh0 = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

or like this:

```
var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Robin");
```

Then set the active cell and retrieve the column index:

```
var editedCell = sh0.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
```

And do the logic for the sort:

```
var columnToSortBy = 1;
var tableRange = "a2:I30";

if(editedCell == columnToSortBy){   
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
}
```

Complete code, a bit shortened:

```
function onEdit(){
  var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var editedCell = sh0.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 1) { 
    var range = sh0.getRange("A2:I30");
    range.sort({column: 1});
  }
}
```

Comment: @oohrogerplamer You can accept the answer by marking it, see this [faq#howtoask] area. You're welcome.

Comment: How can I do this to sort by a column, but so it also sort the other columns too so all the data still matches in the rows?

Answer (score 2):

Get the associated sheet (spreadsheet) and indicate which tab (sheet) you want to have focus:

```
var theSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Robin");
// do the thing
var theSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lucy"); 
// do the other thing
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)