# Auto sort data but by sheet not range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I found this script from [How can I apply a script to only one specific sheet within a spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40360/how-can-i-apply-a-script-to-only-one-specific-sheet-within-a-spreadsheet) to auto sort a column:

```
    function onEdit(){
  var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var editedCell = sh0.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 1) { 
    var range = sh0.getRange("B2:B7");
    range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
  }
}
```

However it's sorting by a single column and not keeping the data in other columns in line by row, so mixing all the data up.

I think I need to sort by sheet rather than range and found this page ["Sorts a sheet by column"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sort(Integer,Boolean)), so I tried replacing:

`range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});`

with

```
sheet.sort(2, false);
```

However now the script doesn't work.

How can I auto sort a single sheet by the values in one column, but keeping all the data in line?

Answer (score 1):

The [`sort`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)) method belongs to the class *Range*, not to the class *Sheet*. Simply put, it always operates on a range. If you want that range to include all the data in a sheet, use the method [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) of the class *Sheet*.

```
var range = sh0.getDataRange();
range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
```

For completeness, I present a customizable script for automatic sorting.

```
  function onEdit() {
    var sheetToSort = "Sheet Name"; // enter name of sheet 
    var columnEdited = 1;           // sort when this column is edited
    var columnSort = 2;             // sort by this column
    var sortAscending = false;      // true or false here

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() == sheetToSort && editedCell == columnEdited) { 
      var range = sheet.getDataRange();
      range.sort({column: columnSort, ascending: sortAscending});
    }
  }
```